# Visual Studio Code Extension for Navigation in Java Project with CTRL + Click

Tags: visual-studio-code

is their a Extension to get the behaviour like eclipse/intellij to press CTRL and click on a type to navigate to this type?

cheers
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the `Java Extension Pack` extension and check if in the system variables you have the JAVA_HOME variable created.

After that, the Ctrl+click behaviour works fine

Comment: no, my vscode java dev environment still not working

Comment: Are you using Java 11 or superior version? As far as I know, it doesn't work with lower versions than that